# Convert value to string using #define

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

My task is to convert a float or integer value to string in **C**. I can't use sprintf since I am working in embedded platform. So I thought to use something like this.

```
#define CURRENT(STRING,S_NO,VALUE) (str = "S"#S_NO#VALUE"A")
```

and invoking it like this

```
int a=10,b=20;
CURRENT(str,a,b);
```

So str should be `S1020A`. But I am getting `SabA`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The C preprocessor run at compile time. When you `#define` things, you aren't making a function.

Answer (score 3):

Macros are evaluated before compilation so `CURRENT(str,a,b);` is expanded using the variable names `a` and `b` rather than their values which may only be available at runtime.

To convert an `int` to a `char` array at runtime without use of [`sprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) etc. use [itoa](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/) if available or you could write a function like the following (untested!)

```
#define MAX_INT_STRING_BYTES (11)

void IntToString(int val, char* str)
{
    char reversed[MAX_INT_STRING_BYTES]
    int index, i = 0;
    bool negative = false;
    if (val == 0) {
        *str++ = '0';
        *str = '\0';
        return;
    }
    if (val < 0) {
        negative = true;
    }
    while(val != 0) {
        reversed[index++] = (char)('0' + abs(val % 10));
        val /= 10;
    }
    if (negative) {
        *str++ = '-';
    }
    for (i = index; i > 0; i--) {
        *str++ = reversed[i - 1]);
    }
    *str = '\0';
}
```

Comment: `itoa` is nonstandard (win-only) and a very bad api anyway. Always use `snprintf`.

Comment: @R.. Thanks, I hadn't realised it was windows only. The OP isn't able to use `sprintf` so I guess that leaves him with some variant of my suggested code...

Answer (score 2):

It only knows what the value of a and b is at runtime, and preprocessor directives are resolved at compile time. Thus what you're trying to do won't work.

You can however do something like:

```
#define CURRENT(STRING,S_NO,VALUE) sprintf(STRING, "S%i%iA", S_NO, VALUE)
```

Or just make it a function.

Or just call the sprintf directly instead of CURRENT.